error: could not execute query: ERROR: schema "_heroku" does not exist
I use Heroku to deploy my app and changed my plan from Basic to Essential 1 on the Postgresql add-on this morning.
Since then, I cannot manage to download my database in a local environment.
Here is the script I run, that was working until now :
 task :download_staging_db do
  puts %x{echo "Setting environment to development"}
  puts %x{rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development}
  puts %x{echo "Dropping existing DB"}
  puts %x{rake db:drop}
  puts %x{echo "Downloading staging DB"}
  puts %x{heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL <my_db_name> --exclude-table-data="versions" --app evening-meadow-24924}
end

And the error message I get from Heroku when running it :
[...]
pg_restore: creating EVENT TRIGGER "log_create_ext"
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "_heroku" does not exist
Command was: CREATE EVENT TRIGGER "log_create_ext" ON "ddl_command_end"
   EXECUTE FUNCTION "_heroku"."create_ext"();


pg_restore: creating EVENT TRIGGER "log_drop_ext"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 4450; 3466 2315888 EVENT TRIGGER log_drop_ext heroku_admin
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "_heroku" does not exist
Command was: CREATE EVENT TRIGGER "log_drop_ext" ON "sql_drop"
   EXECUTE FUNCTION "_heroku"."drop_ext"();


pg_restore: creating EVENT TRIGGER "validate_extension"
pg_restore: from TOC entry 4451; 3466 2315890 EVENT TRIGGER validate_extension heroku_admin
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "_heroku" does not exist
Command was: CREATE EVENT TRIGGER "validate_extension" ON "ddl_command_end"
   EXECUTE FUNCTION "_heroku"."validate_extension"();


pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 6

Any idea on what could be going wrong here ? I found no help on StackOverflow, and opened a ticket on Heroku support, but haven’t had a response so far.

heroku pg:pull is used to copy one Heroku managed database to another. If you want to download your remote database and use it to restore your local database you want to use the pg_dump and pg_restore utilities. Also using puts %x{echo ...} is extremely redundant. Just use puts to write to standard out.

heroku pg:backups:download --app evening-meadow-24924 and pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U julien -d <db> latest.dump
returns the same error as the one shown above. Also, no mention of this _heroku schema is present when i enter the psql console and enter \dx, the only schemas for extensions are public and pg_catalog

Did any one find a solution to this.  I have just run in to the same issue.  To solve it I am converting the dump file to SQL, then editing it.  Fortunately my DB is very small so I can this for now

To covert  dump => sql use:  'pg_restore -f file.sql file.dump'  The offending lines are at the very end of the sql file.  because I cant find a way to go back (sql => dump).  I have to replace every occurrence of the owner with the new local owner.  and restore using psql

I am having the exact same problem. Have you found a solution? It seems this started happening after the last update my machine did.

I also have this problem. I tried updating the Heroku CLI, but no luck.
If you have this problem and just need to restore one backup: you can use a hex editor to null out the offending lines in the .dump file, ie EXECUTE FUNCTION "_heroku"."create_ext"();. Specifically, search the offending "_heroku" text, and null out all the text around it, beginning with the first character starting after the 0x00, up to the terminating 0x00.
Sorry, it's not a great solution, but when I needed to restore a single backup, it was a life saver.

Same issue, here is the support ticket I submitted to heroku in case anyone else wants to copy it:

Documentation at
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-postgres-using-cli#pg-push-and-pg-pull
reads in part,
"pg:pull can be used to pull remote data from a Heroku Postgres
database to a database on your local machine."
This is the workflow we are following and has worked for years. Now we
get the error,
"pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: schema "_heroku"
does not exist"
It would be helpful if you could advise how we are supposed to specify
the heroku schema, or else update the documentation. Please let us know.

Edit: I found despite the error, the local copy database contains data and seems to load in my application.

I got it to work by leveraging the --section option.
I essentially only use --section=pre-data --section=data, omitting --section-post-data
heroku pg:backups:download --app my-app

PGUSER=user PGPASSWORD=password \
pg_restore --no-owner --section=pre-data --section=data -h localhost -d database latest.dump

It works as my app does not use any of the data within post-data

Post-data items consist of definitions of indexes, triggers, rules and constraints other than validated check constraints.

See pg_restore docs -> Options
This way I omit the part of the dump file that wants to create the event triggers that ultimately fail as OP describes.
I am aware this does not work, if you have to restore event triggers of your own, but maybe it helps someone with a similar setup as me to avoid headaches.

The problem seems to be fixed now but will still affect old backups, but if you have an older backup of this style, here is the workaround (source: https://help.heroku.com/HYME3MD5/unexpected-statements-in-the-backup-from-a-essential-x-database-is-causing-local-pg_restore-to-fail):
The _heroku schema is an internal schema that'll exist in our Essential databases that are built on Amazon Aurora and it shouldn't impact with the actual data restore.
However, there is a workaround which is essentially using the pg_restore --use-list argument to filter out event triggers
The first step is to get a list from the dump file via:
pg_restore -l database.dump > unfiltered.list

Which would like something like the following:
2; 3079 31308 EXTENSION - pg_stat_statements 
4304; 0 0 COMMENT - EXTENSION pg_stat_statements 
4149; 3466 31303 EVENT TRIGGER - extension_before_drop heroku_admin
4150; 3466 31304 EVENT TRIGGER - log_create_ext heroku_admin
4151; 3466 31305 EVENT TRIGGER - log_drop_ext heroku_admin
4152; 3466 31306 EVENT TRIGGER - validate_extension heroku_admin

Then you would comment out the event triggers with a semicolon:
sed -e '/EVENT TRIGGER/ s/./;&/' unfiltered.list > filtered.list

Which the results would look something like the following:
2; 3079 31308 EXTENSION - pg_stat_statements 
4304; 0 0 COMMENT - EXTENSION pg_stat_statements 
;4149; 3466 31303 EVENT TRIGGER - extension_before_drop heroku_admin
;4150; 3466 31304 EVENT TRIGGER - log_create_ext heroku_admin
;4151; 3466 31305 EVENT TRIGGER - log_drop_ext heroku_admin
;4152; 3466 31306 EVENT TRIGGER - validate_extension heroku_admin

Then you can run the restore using the --use-list argument:
pg_restore -d foo --use-list filtered.list --no-owner database.dump

Which results with the following where there are no errors when restoring in the local database:
pg_restore --verbose -d foo --use-list filtered.list --no-owner database.dump
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: creating EXTENSION "pg_stat_statements"
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "EXTENSION pg_stat_statements"

